# Create settings for myApplication Iphone

Tags: iphone

I am new to iPhone development.

I've seen many applications, which have their settings stored in the iPhone's setting app.  For example, Default User Name & Password are stored in settings for "myApp."

Whenever the user starts "myApp", userName & password are loaded from the settings app.

How would I implement this functionality into my own app?

any links / any help / any source code / samples

Thanks in advance for being nice to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some relevant docs to take a look at:

1. [Apple's doc for settings within the settings app](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ApplicationSettings/ApplicationSettings.html)
2. [tutorial on creating settings within the settings app](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/tutorial/how-to-create-an-iphone-preferences-file)

Comment: hey buddy thanks, but i found that tutorial before you posted.

Comment: Yep ! A new Huge Question.
My App. required following
if user has set language -> Arabic -> in "myApp" settings
the every input keyboard should be Arabic?

Comment: Question is 

"how to set the language for specific application(myApp)?"

Comment: Apple doesn't provide API access to temporarily or permanently alter the system/keyboard language.  If you want to ensure that your users are using an Arabic keyboard, you would have to build your own keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] will get you the defaults object, from which you can access keyFor and setKeyFor to get/set values. For example [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"UseSounds"] returns 'true' if the user has elected to turn sounds off, and your settings pane defines 'UseSounds' as the key.

[NSUserDefaults reference](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Ok Mr.Blue ! But Question is 
# [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"UseArabic"] #
returns true

then,

how to set all keyboards Arabic in my Application????

Comment: That's a separate question from the one you asked. I don't believe it's possible with the APIs that Apple provide at the moment. I suspect keyboard layout is a property of the phone as a whole.

If you want to have a configurable keyboard, then you may well have to emulate your own, with all the difficulties that that involves.