# How to place my application's Settings in iPhone's "Settings" screen

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm a beginner!
I want to place my application's settings in the iPhone's "Settings" screen, please help me!

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217431/create-settings-for-myapplication-iphone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ApplicationSettings/ApplicationSettings.html) is the best place to look. That link has loads of information, and even a tutorial to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Webscale has a nice tutorial on the subject. I know the [link](http://blog.webscale.co.in/?p=274) for the tutorial on Child Panes ("subviews" for the settings), but since they are have some problems with their server at the moment, I can't give you the link to the other tutorial. But just follow the link in a couple of days and find the other tutorial in the description.